# How can I create a JavaScript regex for finding email addresses in strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a logic app which is triggered by emails in an inbox. It is all working, except for some emails are getting through when I don't want them. Or rather an email signature with an image description of image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990 is getting through.
I think it might be my regex that is allowing it, but I am not very good with regex.

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
var reg = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/gi;
var emailData = " \n\n'Phonenumber2@test.com'\n\n \n\n  DevOps\n[cid:image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990]\n\n ";
    
//Matching email signatures
var matches = emailData .match(reg);

console.log(matches);
```

I need the regex to return a list of any email addresses, but they need to be fully formed. Unlike the one mentioned above which is missing the .com (or .org etc).

Comment: Your regex returns `["Phonenumber2@test.com", "image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990"]`, so what is the problem?

Comment: based on which condition do you want to say `image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990` is not a valid email? maybe no numbers behind the last `.` or restrict amount of characters after last `.` ?

Comment: I dont want that second string, as its not an email address. I only want what looks like a valid email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex (allowing everything which has an `@` and a `.`)

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/gm;
const str = `Phonenumber2@test.com
Phonenumber2@test.info
image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990
Phonenumber2@test.org`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

**#1 No numbers allowed after last `.`**

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z_-]+)/gm;
const str = `Phonenumber2@test.com
Phonenumber2@test.info
image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990
Phonenumber2@test.org`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

**#2 Restrict characters after last `.`** to be min 2 and max 7 characters `{2,7}$`

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,7}$)/gm;
const str = `Phonenumber2@test.com
Phonenumber2@test.info
image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990
Phonenumber2@test.org`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

**#3 Define a list of possible top-level domain names** like `(com|org|info)`

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.(com|org|info)$)/gm;
const str = `Phonenumber2@test.com
Phonenumber2@test.info
image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990
Phonenumber2@test.org`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    console.log(m[0])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions! I have one problem with it, and I think its the input. I am passing in a string from a logic app step that strips out the HTML from the email, and it looks like this : 
var email = "EmailBot.Queue@company.com>\nSubject: FW:\n\n \n\n \n\n'Phonenumber2@test.com'\n\n \n\n       Email Signature | Dev Team\n[cid:image001.png@01D766B1.7C184990]\n\n";

When I run that through my script, it comes out with no matches.

Comment: I got it. I just used replace to take out any characters I want to ignore.

Comment: @evolmonster the problem was most probably the `$` at the end. The `$` makes sure to be an end. Use this regex tool wo practice and get explanations: https://regex101.com/r/HCM4y7/1/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at - https://ihateregex.io/expr/email/

Hate to break it to you but email match via Regex are hard if not impossible.

one way would be matching things with domain name [TDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) endings ( you can create a group of all tdn and match or just limit the end part of regex - [modified regex](https://regexr.com/60g7u) and filter it out from there onwards.

Comment: This particular regex is part of an azure logic app. I read the email from the body of emails sent to a certain inbox. I figured regex/javascript would be the way to go. But if you are saying a regex wont catch everything, maybe I need another solution?